# Using Rexml to parse RSS feed but heavy data not loading on device in Rhomobile

Tags: rhomobile, rexml, rss-reader

I am using Rexml for reading the RSS feed and is working fine with small size of feed.
The large size feed is not working on device although working fine on simulator.
How can i handle large size data?

Comment: What sizes is it working on, what sizes is it breaking on? And what code do you have?

Comment: working well with 4KB and breaking on 108 KB.. Here is the code:     to download :  Rho::AsyncHttp.download_file(
      :url => 'http://164.100.47.5/RSSFEED/Atom.xml',
      :filename => @@file_name,
      :headers => {},
      :callback => (url_for :action => :feed_display_static),
      :callback_param => "" )

Answer (score 0):

To read RSS feed, why are you using Rho::AsyncHttp.download_file(). 
use Rho::AsyncHttp.get().